# Missing values in GLMM

Tags: regression, random-effects-model, model, glmm, mixed-model

I am creating a GLMM based on a experiment where each subject has 2 repeats. In some instances though there is only data for one of a given subjects repeats for most there is data for both. Can I still justify having subject as a random effect?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should still use subject as a random effect.

Look at it the other way around: do missing values mean that you *don't* need to model that multiple (other) observations come from the same individual? No, they don't.

Mixed models work just fine with missing values.